Convert a LIST specific 2 properties result to a 2D array
I've a list of class containing different type of properties:
public class Test
{
    public string grade { get; set; }
    public int minVal { get; set; }
    public int maxVal { get; set; }
}

However, I want the result set to be in the form of a 2D based to Select 2 columns (MIN and MAX val) and add them into 2d array like [[0,10],[11,20],[21,24],...] this type of format to consume this array in javascript to populate chartjs graph.
I've tried few solutions like :
var result = list.Select(team => new string[] { "["+team.minVal +","+ team.maxVal +"]"}).ToArray(); 
var result = list.Select(team => new string[] { team.minVal ,team.maxVal }).ToArray();

but can't figuring out the desired solution of 2D array[[minVal,maxVal],[minVal,maxVal],[minVal,maxVal],[minVal,maxVal],....] using linq query. Is there something single liner solution to this?

list.Select(x => new int[]{x.minVal, x.maxVal}).ToArray();

Do you want a true 2D multi-dimensional array int[,] or is a jagged array of arrays int[][] acceptable?

Answers from one of these questions might be what you are looking for.

@T N looking for true 2D array all respective elements placed on 0 index of array.

@iakobski I've tried your solution already.  And relevant links shared above
